# Create structured list from Excel data

Tags: python, excel, list, format, line

Hello everyone I'm using Python 2.7.3 and I'm trying to structure my output list where the data prints under each category.

My data reads:

```
('State', 'Heart Disease Death Rate (2007)', 'Motor Vehicle Death Rate (2009)', 'Teen Birth Rate (2009)', 'Adult Smoking (2010)', 'Adult Obesity (2010)')

('Alabama', '235.5', '18.01', '50.7', '21.90%', '33.00%')
('Alaska', '147.9', '9.16', '44.5', '20.40%', '25.20%')
('Arizona', '152.5', '12.24', '50.6', '13.50%', '24.70%')
('Arkansas', '221.8', '20.25', '59.3', '22.90%', '30.90%')
('California', '177.9', '8.34', '36.6', '12.10%', '24.70%')
```

I need the list to read as:

```
 'State', 'Heart Disease', Vehicle Death Rate', 'Teen Birth Rate', 'Adult Smoking , 'Adult Obesity

Alabama'        '235.5',        18.01',             '50.7',          '21.90%',        33.00%' 
Alaska,        '147.9',         '9.16',             '44.5',          '20.40%',        25.20% 
Arizona',      '152.5',         '12.24', '           50.6',          '13.50%',       '24.70%'
Arkansas',      '221.8',        '20.25',            '59.3',          '22.90%',       '30.90%'
```

Heres what I have so far:

```
import csv
import pandas
import string, re

output = []
file1 = []

risk = open('riskfactors.csv', 'r').read() #find the file
reader = csv.reader(risk, delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')


try:
   with open('riskfactors.csv', 'rU') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        cells = line.split(",")
        output.append((cells[0], cells[1], cells[5], cells[7], cells[11], cells[13]))
    for elem in output:
        print(elem)
```

No Errors

I need 2.7.3 because its the only way for me to use `import pandas`.

What should I do to make this print correctly?

I feel like I'm so close, what am I missing? Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Pandas has CSV parsing tools: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html

Comment: So at the moment you have the list at the top ('My data reads') and you want to compile it into a string that looks like a table?

Comment: yes it already prints just need to compile it into a string that looks like a table look like the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the list as a formatted string you can use the string.format function, which lets you pad the value out with whitespace to a specified length.

For instance, if you were to do

```
print "{0:<20}".format( "test" )
```

you could get "test                ", which is the format string with whitespace appended to make 20 characters. You can use this to create a tabular structure, where all of the columns are a set width. Note that if the format string is over 20 (in this example) characters then it will not truncate it, you will have to handle that yourself (i.e change 'Heart Disease Death Rate (2007)' to 'Heart Disease'.

So, in your example you could display the string using the following code

```
outstring = ""
for item in output:
    for cell in item:
        outstring += "{0:<20}  ".format( cell ) #change 20 to whatever you want the column width to be
    outstring += "\n"

print outstring
```